# how to set ID for many Ps inside parent using for loop?

Tags: javascript, html

i have some `<p>` inside `<div>`, how to set `ID` for all of them using `for` loop?

`HTML`

```
<div id="article">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
<div>
```

the result will be like that:

```
<div id="article">
    <p id="p1">1</p>
    <p id="p2">1</p>
    <p id="p3">1</p>
    <p id="p4">1</p>
</div>
```

i made this code but not working

```
var i;
var sI = document.querySelectorAll("#article p");

for (i = 0; i < sI.length; i++){

    sI[i].id = "p" + i + 1;
     
}
```

Comment: "not working" really doesn't describe a problem that anyone can help you with without wild guessing. Please clarify.

Comment: it's pretty clear, please see Alexanderbira Answer, thank you.

Comment: Just because somebody took an educated guess and happened to give you the answer you wanted doesn't make this question clear.

Comment: I have clarified what the target of the code is, and I have clarified the final result of the code, And I put my code so that I think it has a problem.
I don’t know how to explain more, 4 people have answered, And I think that they all understood what is required from the code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm too tired to deal with the poor grammar. Rereading the question, "the result will be like that" was a confusing turn a phrase. I didn't know if that represented the problem or the desired result.

Comment: I work hard to improve my English, sorry for this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
sI[i].id = "p" + i + 1;
```

with:

```
sI[i].id = "p" + (i + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since in javascript the + operator is used for both concatenation and addition, you need to put i+1 in a bracket, so that the first index gets increased and then you add it to p generate a unique id.

> "p" + (i+1) will work

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it more gracefully, you can use this

```
document.querySelectorAll("#article p").forEach(function(node,i){
    node.id = 'p'+(i+1)
})
```

Comment: @Aluan Haddad Thanks for pointing out. I have edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Adding brackets to isolate your addition will add and not concatenate

like so `"p" + (i + 1)`

```js
var i;
var sI = document.querySelectorAll("#article p");

for (i = 0; i < sI.length; i++) {

  sI[i].id = "p" + (i + 1);

}
```

```html
<div id="article">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <div>
```